# How to unpack a slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

How can i unpack a slice in golang?

I have a slice,

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5, ...n ]
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to generate new variables dynamically for the length of the slice.
The output should look something like this

```
Var a = 1, b= 2, c=3, n=last number in slice
```

Comment: What do you mean by achieve this? as an output?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i want to have as an output.

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can't, and it would be useless if you could. Can you update your question to indicate what you're actually trying to accomplish? There's certainly a way to do it, but what you're describing is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering that the thing you want is `dynamic variable allocation`. I guess you cannot do so. Instead you can use `Go Map` to store your data as `key-value` format.

```golang
func main() {
    mySlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    myVariables := make(map[string]int)
    ch := 'a'
    for _, value := range mySlice {
        key := fmt.Sprintf("%c", ch)
        myVariables[key] = value
        ch++
    }
    fmt.Println(myVariables)
}
```

The output will be:

```
map[a:1 b:2 c:3 d:4 e:5 f:6 g:7 h:8 i:9 j:10]
```

You can also generate the key name randomly, visit [here](https://www.calhoun.io/creating-random-strings-in-go/) for details